# Complicated .txt file Parsing Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I need to parse a text file in the form:

```
Encanto, 6/101-105, 7/320-322
Flora, 1/2-5
Vista, 7/67-70
WORK ORDER
```

I know how to parse a .txt file that has lines in the form "name, number" into two separate ArrayLists using the following method:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
allNames.add(line.split(", ")[0]);
allNums.add(Integer.parseInt(line.split(",\\s+")[1]));
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

Now I must get the Lists to have these items:

```
ArrayList<String> names = {"Encanto", "Flora", "Vista", "WORK ORDER"};

ArrayList<String> lots = {"Bld.6 101", "Bld.6 102", "Bld.6 103", "Bld.6 104", "Bld.6 105", "Bld.7 320", "Bld.7 321", "Bld.7 322"};
ArrayList<String> lots1 = {"Bld.1 2", "Bld.1 3", "Bld.1 4", "Bld.1 5",};
ArrayList<String> lots2 = {"Bld.7 67", "Bld.7 68", "Bld.7 69", "Bld.7 70"};
```

Comment: It is also not clear what your problem is. You know how to use `String.split()` to pick apart a line; that will work for the new format you show, so what's the problem?

Comment: I am unsure how to save the number before the slash, before the hypen or after the hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this Parser class

```
class Parser {
    String parseName(String line) {
        String[] blocks = line.split(", ");
        if (blocks.length > 0) {
            return blocks[0];
        }
        return null;
    }

    List<String> getLots(String line) {
        List<String> lotList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] blocks = line.split(", ");
        for (String block : blocks) {
            // I suppose that lot line will always have "/" and "-"
            if (block.contains("/") && block.contains("-")) {
                lotList.addAll(generateLots(block));
            }
        }
        return lotList;
    }

    private List<String> generateLots(String block) {
        List<String> lots = new ArrayList<>();
        String prefix = "Bld.";
        String bldNumber = block.substring(0, block.indexOf("/"));
        int lowest = Integer.parseInt(block.substring(block.indexOf("/") + 1, block.indexOf("-")));
        int highest = Integer.parseInt(block.substring(block.indexOf("-") + 1, block.length()));
        for (int i = lowest; i <= highest; i++) {
            lots.add(prefix + bldNumber + " " + i);
        }
        return lots;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your code

```
// create a new Parser object
Parser parser = new Parser();
// get name
System.out.println(parser.parseName(line));
// get lots
List<String> lotList = parser.getLots(line);
for (String lot : lotList) {
    System.out.println(lot);
}
```

=========================================================

Edit:
To answer your comment, you can create lot lists on the fly. If I refer to your question, it will be like this

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
Parser parser = new Parser();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> lotsList = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    names.add(parser.parseName(line));
    lotsList.add(parser.getLots(line));
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

Comment: Very beautiful code Hendra, however my only uncertainty is that I need to create 'n' amount of lot Lists, 'n' being the number of lines in the .txt file. I don't think your code allows me to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much!